# Spring Integration AWS Local SQS

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I want to implement spring-integration-aws to send and receive messages with SQS. I am looking at localstack and would like to know the recommendation of the spring team.

Which tool/api should I use for local setup of spring  integration flows for SQS inbound and outbound adapters?

Also, will there be examples of AWS in spring-integration-samples in future? I am looking for an example with xml config that reads the aws config from credentials and send and receive messages via outbound adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what recommendation you expect from us, but I see an answer in your own question - `Localstack`: https://github.com/localstack/localstack.

In the project test we indeed use this tool over a docker container:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/lock/DynamoDbLockRegistryTests.java#L62

We don't have such a test against SQS, but the configuration technique is similar.

I recall I heard that Testcontainers project can be used for testing AWS services locally as well: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/localstack/

We don't have resources to write samples for this project.

Comment: To simulate AWS in local setup, I ended up using dockerised ElasticMQ with queues created at startup